# What is the easiest way to download data from an URL in Cocoa-Touch?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, cocoa

The string is about 500 chars and need to be downloaded at app start.

Comment: And what will you do if the device does not have an internet connection?

Comment: Tell the user to get internet access, before using the app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If speed is not crucial, you can simply write:

```
NSString *string = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://example.com/str.txt"]];
```

However, if you want to be elegant, idiomatic and secure (if the above code times out, iOS will kill your app!), use NSURLConnection, or simply wrap the above code into an NSThread.

NSThread docs: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSThread_Class/Reference/Reference.html

NSURLConnection docs:
http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Hope it helps.

Comment: What if there is no connection and the download fails?

Comment: Then method 1 will return nil, or NSURLConnnection will notify its delegate.

Comment: Threads are a little low level you may be better of looking at `NSOperation` and `NSOperationQueue`'s [Concurrency Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091)